# Создать gradle скрипт запуска

Tags: android-studio, gradle

хочу создать себе скрипт в Андроид Студио, который будет последовательно повторять обычные нажатия на кнопки (в студии):

- Sync project with gradle
- clean build
- make build
- Run app

подскажите, как это можно реализовать и куда смотреть?

Comment: Sync project with gradle нужно только если изменились настройки проектов. ¿А зачем последовательно нажимать clean build, make build, Run app вместо однократного нажатия Run app?

Comment: @user7860670 проект оооочень тугой и неоптимизированный. между ветками есть изменения настройки проекта. и чтобы переключиться между ветками помогает только данная последовательность манипуляций. и уже надоело самому это тыкать и ждать выполнения каждого действия.

Comment: Попробуйте AutoIt.